# Execution order of methods when @Test is at class level

Tags: java, testng

There are a lot of questions on the execution order of `TestNG` tests, but I haven't found one that specifically answers this question - unless I just cannot find it.

I know there's things to do that can achieve what I'm looking for, such as:

1. `@Test` above every test method within the class with the use of `Priority`
2. `@Test` above every test method within the class with the use of `Depends on`
3. The use of `preserve-order` in the XML file

However, what I want to know is:

If you declare `@Test` at the class level, not the method level, how to "preserve" the order in which the methods are declared? Can you even do this?

For example, if my class looks like this:

```
@Test
public class mySampleClass
{
    public void test()
    {
        //Run first - First method in the class
    }
    
    public void run()
    {
        //Run second - Second method in the class
    }
    
    public void execute()
    {
        //Run last - Last method in the class
    }
}
```

Can I ensure that when I run this that the methods are executed in the order they are within the class instead of alphabetically?

Comment: Why do unit tests need order? if it's the unit test.

Comment: Thank you for the reply @VeKe :). It's actually not unit tests.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure why you want your tests to run that way, Even though it is not possible to do it directly, it IS possible using a `MethodInterceptor`:

```java
public class MyInterceptor implements IMethodInterceptor {

    // keep your list of method names in order
    private static final List<String> order = List.of("test", "run", "execute");
    
    @Override
    public List<IMethodInstance> intercept(List<IMethodInstance> methods, ITestContext context) {
        methods.sort(Comparator.comparing(m -> order.indexOf(m.getMethod().getMethodName())));
        return methods;
    }
}
```

Now add the `@Listeners(value = MyInterceptor.class)` annotation to your class.

**NOTE:** `List.of` is available only in java 9+, if you are using a lower version, you could use `Arrays.asList`.

Comment: Thank you for the answer :) I don't NEED to specifically have it run as I asked in my question above, however I was wondering if it's possible to do that. It's easier to name the methods descriptively and have them placed in the order you want to be executed and instead of `@Test` by each method (if not explicitly needed) you just `@Test` at the class level and you're done.

Comment: @EitelDagnin Anyways, the method interceptor could be used to modify the order/ add/remove tests in any way we like.